# How often vs. What days

Tags: word-choice

> 1. Q: How often do you jog ?
>      A: I jog every day.
> 2. Q: What days do you jog?
>      A: I jog every day.

Which is correct?

Comment: What makes you think that only one is correct?

Comment: How often do you jog?  Twice a week.  What days do you jog?  Mondays and Thursdays.  (Same basic answer as Hot Licks', but more helpful.)

Answer (score 3):

To determine which is correct you have to question your intention in asking the question. And yes, both can yield the same answer.

When asking "how often"...you are asking a question of frequency. Depending on the context of the question, most likely you will receive an answer including an adverbial of frequency ([Src](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time/how-often)):

- always
- never
- normally e.g. "Normally twice a day."
- occasionally
- often
- rarely e.g. "Oh rarely. Maybe once a month with my friend Maria"
- seldom
- sometimes e.g. "Sometimes in the spring and summer."
- usually e.g. "I usually jog 3 times during the weekdays and rest on the weekend."

That frequency is not necessarily bound by the "days of the week". The time boundary is a determined by the responder or the context of the conversation.

When asking a question beginning with "[what](http://merriam.com/dictionary/what)..." you are asking for specificity or identification . The question "What days do you jog?" has already specified 'days'. Therefore your answers should come within the context of days of the week.

e.g. 
I jog on Sundays, Wednesdays and Fridays

(OR as in your example:)

I jog everyday.

If you changed the context, the answer could differ. For example, say you were asking a teammate in a multi-day marathon the same question. He/She might respond, "I jog on the first and last day."